# App crashes when spinner is touched

Tags: android, arrays, crash, spinner

First of all, this is my first time here, so pardon me if I fail on manners.

I am making an easy spinner. It reads a string-array located in `string.xml` and then compares the country code to select the adecuate image from the drawable folder (where all the images are propely located). Everything works fine, it seems the spinner loads the info, but when I touch it to display, the app crashes.

If anyone could help I would very grateful

Adapter Class:

```
public class CustomAdapterPhone2 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public CustomAdapterPhone2(Context context, int resource, String [] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items_phone, parent, false);
    TextView label=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_phone_textview);
    String [] countries = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    String [] aux = countries[position].split(",");
    label.setText(aux[1]);
    String aux2 = aux[1].trim().toLowerCase();
   // int aux3 = String.valueOf(aux2);

    ImageView icon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_phone_image);
    icon.setImageResource(getContext().getResources().getIdentifier( aux2, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName()));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Main Class:

```
 Spinner spinner_country_code = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.phone_spinner);
    spinner_country_code.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    CustomAdapterPhone2 customAdapterPhone2 = new CustomAdapterPhone2(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_spinner_items_phone,recourseList);
    spinner_country_code.setAdapter(customAdapterPhone2);
```

The spinner layout only has a textview and an ImageView, nothing fancy.
I've been stuck with this for days, and the worse thing is that I've already other spinners working.

Comment: provide your logcat..

Comment: create a field of type **Context** in your adapter class , set it in your constructor then use it where you need instead of **getContext()**

Comment: where is the line that has the problem ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following code instead of your adapter code because your are using extending simple ArrayAdapter for image use BaseAdapter.

```
public class CustomAdapterPhone2 extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] countries;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapterPhone2(Context contexts, int resource, String[] objects) {
        /*super(context, resource, objects);*/
        this.context = contexts;
        this.countries = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.CountryCodes);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countries.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items_phone, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_phone_textview);

        String[] aux = countries[position].split(",");
        label.setText(aux[1]);
        String aux2 = aux[1].trim().toLowerCase();
        // int aux3 = String.valueOf(aux2);

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_phone_image);
        icon.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(aux2, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I have tested it working fine.

Comment: Thank you for the effort , but i already managed to find a solution on my own. Anyway i give you the correct answer

Comment: And also, ArrayAdapter "should" work as well as BaseAdapter, because ArrayAdapter extends form BaseAdapter